# Protecting Worklight console based on AD groups using a WAS system and WASLTPA

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

We're using Worklight in a WAS environment and we need to protect the WL console from just anybody logging in and manipulating applications. We have a working configuration using WASLTPAModule going against Active Direcotry. The WAS cluster is using global security with a federated AD configuration. This configuration works to provide authentication into the console.

The problem is that anybody that has a valid account in AD can login to the console.

I have not seen any documentation or information on how to constrain the authorization to use the console to specific AD groups.  How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Worklight 6.1, the WebSphereLoginModule has an optional "role" parameter to specify the JEE role that the user must belong to in order to successfully authenticate:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_wasltpamodule_login_module.html

Then in WebSphere, you would use the usual role mapping capability to map your AD groups to that role.